# modify automatically a record of a table at a specific date using cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cron

i am new in cakephp
I have a table named souscriptions this table has a field called expiration_date and another field called "state" that can have only two value : 0 or 1.

**i want to change automatically the value of the "state" field when the current system date equals to the the value of the expiration_date field. i am using cakePHP. i have more than one million records in the subscription table.**

How can i  perform it with cakephp ? Thanks for your precious answers.

Answer (score 2):

Create a CakePHP Shell, read the subscriptions in Chunks of X records to avoid a memory overflow and repeat that until no more subscriptions to process are left. Then run the shell with a Cronjob every day or whatever interval you prefer.

References:

- [Consoles and Shells](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html)
- [Running Shells as Cronjobs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html)